# Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make extension that add field between these two [UserID]
then edit the script file on the website [ or overwrite it ] so after clicking search i will get search result by userids

i`m learning but i know the basics
i dont need full code
just code which select the place on the website

```
<table class="dt" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="dth">Calloff Number</td>
        <td class="dtc1">
            <input class="ipt" type="text" name="calloff_no" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td class="dth">Dates</td>
        <td class="dtc1">
            From
            <input class="ipt" type="text" name="datefrom" value="">
            &nbsp;to&nbsp;
            <input class="ipt" type="text" name="dateto" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td class="dth">Company</td>
        <td class="dtc1">
            <input class="ipt" type="text" name="company" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td class="dth">Account</td>
        <td class="dtc1">
            <input class="ipt" type="text" name="account" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td class="dth">Calloff Status</td>
        <td class="dtc1">
            <div><input type="checkbox" class="ipt" id="status_" 0"="" name="status" checked="checked" value="0"><label for="status_0">Pending</label></div><div><input type="checkbox" class="ipt" id="status_" 1"="" name="status" value="1"><label for="status_1">Picking in progress</label></div><div><input type="checkbox" class="ipt" id="status_" 2"="" name="status" value="2"><label for="status_2">Part shipped</label></div><div><input type="checkbox" class="ipt" id="status_" 3"="" name="status" value="3"><label for="status_3">Complete</label></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8LiO.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj89K.png)

Comment: I read your question three times but I didn't understand it. If you want to inject scripts into website, use Content scripts.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I read the question 5 times and didn't understand it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.